# Unity keyboard keys - what are their names?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Unity keyboard keys - what are their names?

Is there any list of keyboard key names in Unity somewhere? (class Input)

Because I'm writing a game and I need these names to even move my character around!
Please help!

Comment: Does this help? https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/KeyCode.html

Answer (score 0):

Using strings for keys in Unity has performance implications and is very hard to remember.

I recommend using `KeyCode`s instead (https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/KeyCode.html). This will allow your IDE to autocomplete the names of all of the keys and show dropdowns in the Unity Editor.

Buuut! There are good reasons why you might actually need to use the string names. For example, you might be working with the old Input system and configuring Axis for keys. If this is the case, then I recommend you [check out this answer on the Unity forums](http://answers.unity.com/answers/1378572/view.html).